# how to check if two numbers in a list are the same in Python

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, while-loop, int

I have a little problem with some coding.
This is my code:

```
def sites(x):
    r = []
    sum = 0
    i = 0
    modulo = []
    som = 0
    j = 0
    while i < len(x):
        sum = int(float(x[i])) + (i + 1)
        r.append(sum)
        i = i + 1
    while j < len(x):
        som = r[j] % len(x)
        modulo.append(som)
        j = j + 1
    return modulo
```

If I for example fill in sites("321") this code will give me the list [1, 1, 1]. What I want to do is check if there are numbers in this list that are the same. I was thinking about something like:

```
if modulo[0] != modulo[1] != modulo[2]:
    print "valid"
else:
    print "invalid"
```

This only works when the input in sites is three digits long. I've been brainstorming on how to use a while loop that checks every digit.

All help is very welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a set to remove any dups and check the length after against the original list:

```
if len(set(modulo)) == len(modulo): # if lengths are  equal we have no duplicate nums
     print "valid"
else:
      print "Invalid"
```

If you just want to avoid adding dups keep a set of all nums seen and check before adding:

```
seen = set()
if num not in seen: add it
```

I would also avoid using sum as a variable name as it shadows the builtin python `sum` function.

You can also use `enumerate`,`range` and you don't need to declare variables in python:

```
def sites(x):
    r = []
    modulo = []
    ln = len(x)
    for i,ele in enumerate(x):
        sm = int(float(ele)) + (i + 1)
        r.append(sm)
    for j in range(ln):
        som = r[j] % ln
        modulo.append(som)
    return modulo
```

Or better again use [list comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
def sites(x):
    ln = len(x)
    r = [int(float(ele)) + (i + 1) for i,ele in enumerate(x)]
    modulo = [r[j] % ln for j in range(ln)]
    return modulo
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I had been thinking about how to solve it for over two hours and you come with a clever solution within the first two minutes of asking. I can't express how grateful I am. Have a nice day :)

Answer (score 1):

So I know you got your answer, but I just wanted to chime in and show a more optimized approach to your issue. This will allow you to not loop through the string more than once, and if it's invalid, you might not even stop early.

You can create a generator and loop through it adding to a `seen` list if the value is not already in the list:

```
gen = ((int(float(ele)) + (i + 1)) % len(x) for i,ele in enumerate(x))
seen = set() 
for i in gen:
    if i in seen:
        print 'invalid'
        break
    seen.add(i)
else:
    print 'valid'
```

This has the added benefit of not creating an additional 1-2 lists in memory which could be a problem if your initial string/list is very large.

Comment: This is not really an  efficient solution  as you use a list so lookups are `0(n)` as opposed to the `set` I suggested which is `0(1)` and worst case you still create a second list `seen` which you then throw away with no benefit of a quick lookup

Comment: I agree,  I was thinking more about memory usage rather than raw speed.  I changed it to a set so now it's more memory efficient and faster :)

Comment: Yep, the set makes a difference with larger input.